# Canvas Context2D.drawImage() throws type error for HTMLImageElement even when target is correct type

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, instanceof

I'm trying to resize an image that uses a base64 encoded source. To do this I'm trying to use the canvas element's 2d draw image method for a canvas that is the side I'd like to scale down to.

This is what my method looks like:

```
resizeImage (base64Image) {
  let vm = this

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // let img = document.createElement('img') // I've tried both with the Image constructor and with the document createElement function
    let img = new Image()

    img.onload = () => {
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

      canvas.width = vm.resizeDimensions.width
      canvas.height = vm.resizeDimensions.height

      // at this point, the `this` context is referring to the img element we created
      // this is also the point at which I hit the type error
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, vm.resizeDimensions.width, vm.resizeDimensions.height)
      let uri = canvas.toDataUrl()
      resolve(uri)
    }

    img.src = base64Image
  })
},
```

The thing that's throwing me for a loop is that when I step through the code in the debugger and do my own type check, the image created (regardless of construction method) *is* one of the valid types for the drawImage method:

[image: type checks and error]
*sorry for the crossing arrows. I tried recording a gif but the file size was too large to upload to stackoverflow*.

There's definitely something I'm missing here. Why is a type error being thrown even though I can confirm that the garget is indeed the correct type?

A bit more information: This is a electron/vue prototype for a larger project. The code with this bug is in a branch and subfolder of the project here if you want to dig in: https://github.com/chris-schmitz/matching-game/tree/image-encoding-prototype-errors/prototypes/saving-and-encoding-images.

## Update

Here's a screenshot of the contents of this within the onload callback:

[image: this in callback]

Also, the gif I recorded of the error happening can be found [here](https://github.com/chris-schmitz/matching-game/blob/image-encoding-prototype-errors/prototypes/saving-and-encoding-images/troubleshooting_gifs/type%20error%20that%20shouldn't%20happen.gif):

Comment: `toDataUrl` is spelled wrong? It should be `toDataURL`.

Comment: _at this point, the `this` context is referring to the img element we created.._ Why do you think so?

Comment: Thanks. thanks for that spell check. Corrected in my code.

Comment: @hindmost because I checked it in the debugging step. I'll add a screen shot of this once I'm in that context.

Comment: Why not just pass `img` instead of `this`?

Comment: Holy hell! That worked! I was referring to this because it seemed appropriate to use (this === img, right? (well, wrong apparently)). I have no problem using img especially since it fixed the issue :P ! So my question now (and the answer I would gladly give a check to) is why is it different? in the callback it looks like and I would have assumed that this is the same as img, especially since the type check of this passed. What's the difference? Thanks, btw @hindmost. Regardless of the reasoning that def got me unstuck.

Comment: Don't rely on values in the console. It doesn't always show actual information.

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing that out. I added a couple of console.logs to the code to spit out `console.log(this instanceof HTMLImageElement)` inside  the callback and it did indeed return false. Thanks for the help. If you wanted to submit an answer I'd give you the check.